# I don't how do you call this, but please help me. Calculate the result of...

Tags: factorial

How to calculate the result of:

$$\frac{2012(1!)}{3!}+\frac{2012(2!)}{4!}+\frac{2012(3!)}{5!}+...+\frac{2012(2010!)}{2012!}$$

What is the theory used? Sequence of number? Please help me understand with clear step by step as I haven't learned about this. I only understand that there are some factorial in it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2012(1!)}{3!}+\frac{2012(2!)}{4!}+\frac{2012(3!)}{5!}+...+\frac{2012(2010!)}{2012!}=$$$$2012\sum_{n=1}^{2010}\frac{n!}{(n+2)!}=2012\sum_{n=1}^{2010}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$Because this is a telescoping series, we can easily solve now.

Comment: Sorry,,, I'm still in Junior high school, and don't understand your solution at all. Do you mind re-explaining for me?

Comment: @Pebrianto Do you see how I took the given expression and made it into a sum?  Where is it that you got lost?

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: We should use calculator to calculate that zigma right?